# Unable to get azure OAuth2 token with javascript for O365 Comm-Services

Tags: javascript, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, token

i have a problem and hope you guys can help me.
I want to build a small page for my colleagues that they can check the newest informations from O365 admin-portal.
For that i want to use the "Office 365 Service Communications API"(https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/contoso.com/ServiceComms/Messages)

I already registered the application in my azure-ad so i am already able to get the Information via Postman or Powershell(Invoke-Rest). But i have problem to get it with JavaScript. With normal rest-options i always get a CORS error. Thats why i thought i try it with the MSAL.js library. 
But i cant get it work. Maybe my Code is wrong?!
And i was a little bit confused because in the official docs they say i must deactivate CORS in my browser?! (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-browser --> under prerequisites)

It cant be that difficult... hope you can help me.
Here is my Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://alcdn.msauth.net/lib/1.2.0/js/msal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://alcdn.msauth.net/lib/1.2.0/js/msal.min.js"></script>

<html lang="en">
<script type="text/javascript">
var Demo;

    const msalConfig = {
        auth: {
            clientId: '2076e785-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX'
        }
    };

    const msalInstance = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);

    msalInstance.handleRedirectCallback((error, response) => {
        // handle redirect response or error
    });

    var loginRequest = {
        scopes: ["user.read", "mail.send"] // optional Array<string>
    };

    msalInstance.loginPopup(loginRequest)
        .then(response => {
            // handle response
        })
        .catch(err => {
            // handle error
        });
    // if the user is already logged in you can acquire a token
    if (msalInstance.getAccount()) {
        var tokenRequest = {
            scopes: ["user.read", "mail.send"]
        };
        msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest)
            .then(response => {

            })
            .catch(err => {
                // could also check if err instance of InteractionRequiredAuthError if you can import the class.
                if (err.name === "InteractionRequiredAuthError") {
                    return msalInstance.acquireTokenPopup(tokenRequest)
                        .then(response => {
                            // get access token from response
                            // response.accessToken
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            // handle error
                        });
                }
            });
    } else {
        // user is not logged in, you will need to log them in to acquire a token
    }

    var headers = new Headers();
    var bearer = "Bearer " + Demo;

    var options = {
         method: "GET",
         headers: headers
    };
    var graphEndpoint = "https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/ServiceComms/Messages";

    fetch(graphEndpoint, options)
        .then(resp => {
             //do something with response
        });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi LonBoy, may I know the error message ?

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Comment: May I know if the error shows when you call "Office 365 Service Communications API" ?

Comment: What do you mean? How should i call the API?
With PowerShell or Postman everything works

Comment: If you call the api in js, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is inevitable. The sdk which you used can just enable you can get the access token.

Comment: I just get the Token with this library? Because i get the token, that means the library works... i just get the CORS error when i try to fetch the "....ServiceComms/Message"(Office 365 Service Communications API).
But why? in the official doku they tell my i just need a valid token -> [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-service-communications-api-reference)

Comment: @LonBoy As far as I knew, if we directly call request from one domain to another domain in page, we will meet cors issue. It is a common issue. Regarding how to fix it, please refer to https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9

Comment: @LonBoy Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: That helped a lot. Thanks!!

Comment: @JimXu your comment with the medium.com/xxxx-link helped me. I am not able to accept a comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I knew, we just can use the sdk `msal.js` to request azure ad access token without cors issue. But when we make the fetch request to `https://manage.office.com` in the client-side application(single page application), we will meet the cors error. Because the request is cross domain. Regarding how to fix it, please refer to the  https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9.